# Linux custom init and SIGTERM

Tags: linux, rust, init

I try to build my own init with rust language.
this is my example code :

```
use std::process::Command;

fn main() {
    loop {
        println!("Welcome to custom operating system");
        let result = Command::new("/bin/sh")
            .spawn();

        match result {
            Ok(mut child) => {
                let _r = child.wait();
            }
            Err(_err) => {
                println!("Restart shell")
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**Note:** this code work on my custom kernel without any problem.
now i have a misunderstood about init and SIGTERM signal .
should i implement trap SIGTERM on my init or kernel handle it ?
I read [man 2 kill](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/kill.2.html) but still i have confused .

Comment: `should i implement trap SIGTERM on my init or kernel handle it ?`, both? signal need to be sent by the OS, and handled by the process itself.

Comment: The kernel should handle the case where `init` exits for _any_ reason (not just `SIGTERM`). So it all depends on what you want to happen when your `init` receives `SIGTERM`: should it ignore the signal? should it exit and let the default kernel behaviour take its course? or should it shutdown the OS gracefully?